# Recording audio on Android without saving to external storage

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm writing audio to external storage, but immediately uploading the file and then deleting it.  I would prefer to just obtain the audio data and upload it directly, without having to write to the SD card.

Here is my current code:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/filename.3gp");
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Is there any replacement for my `setOutputFile` call that will write to a Stream of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try using Audiorecord](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/acquire-samples-with-audiorecord-and-maybe-dump-them-t12957.html).

```
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,SAMPPERSEC, 
channelConfiguration,audioEncoding,buffersizebytes);
audioRecord.startRecording(); 
mSamplesRead = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffersizebytes); 
audioRecord.stop();
```